# Deploying an Xamarin.Mac app without app store or internet

Tags: c#, macos, xamarin, mono, xamarin.mac

I need to build a desktop application for Windows (easy with C# .Net) and one for Mac OS X.  The application will be the same for both platforms.

I am still deciding on what is best to use (off-topic question) to do this.  If I chose Xamarin.Mac can I deploy it as a package that gets downloaded to a zip file and installed on a computer with no internet?

I am looking at Xamarin.Mac through it appears Xamarin seems to be cross platform for ios, android and windows instead of mac too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Deploying an Xamarin.Mac app without app store or internet?

In the publish step of the `Xamarin.Mac` app **`Archive and Publish`** process, you have a choice of:

- App Store
- Mac Application (Save to disk)
- Mac Installer Package (Save to disk)

You can choice one of the "save to disk" options and either produce an `.app` or a `.pkg`. How you share that resulting `.app/.pkg` is up to you.

[image]

In terms of using `Xamarin.Forms` to build your macOS UI, review:

- [Preview: Bringing macOS to Xamarin.Forms](https://blog.xamarin.com/preview-bringing-macos-to-xamarin-forms/)

Comment: Can you build a windows and mac app as one and then publish to either os? It would be great if it did.

Comment: @cdub No, they would be separate builds and "app bundles" for each platform. The Mono project supported Windows.Forms and thus you could run a Windows Forms exe on macOS (using an "emulated UI"), but that implementation was never truly completed, was slow, buggy, etc...

Comment: Thanks for your helop as this helps out a lot.