# .Net MAUI (Windows & Mac)

Tags: macos, maui

I have created a .NET MAUI application in Windows Visual Studio 2022. Also I have a MAC fully configured with latest Visual Studio for MAC and Xcode Installed.

When pairing the MAC for windows machine I am able to run the simulators for various IPhone devices(as they are attached to MAC) but when I try to run for the MacCatalyst from my Windows machine it doesnt work.

### Is it possible to create a build for the MAUI application for MacCatalyst from my windows machine.The build should be created in my Windows folder directory.?

I am connected to MAC via my windows Visual studio 2022 .I am expecting it will run the solution as it would do on MAC but its asking me to connect or choose a particular simulator but I want it to be done for Mac catalyst.Trying to build the solution in the Windows itself with reference to MAC

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to create a build for the MAUI application for MacCatalyst from my windows machine.The build should be created in my Windows folder directory.?

Unfortunately, it is not possible to create a build for the MAUI application for MacCatalyst from your Windows machine. You will need to use a Mac to build and deploy the application to MacCatalyst.

There is a similar case you can refer to: [How to run MAUI app (From files generated from Windows -> VS2022) on MAC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70567842/how-to-run-maui-app-from-files-generated-from-windows-vs2022-on-mac). Hope it can help you.